# certbot renew fails - pip = python2.7, pip3 = python 3.8

Tags: python

Ubuntu 20.04
When I run: sudo certbot renew
I get: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1
In fact, if I run certbot at all (ie sudo certbot --version) I get that error.

Investigation has led me to believe the certbot fails when using python2.
My server runs both python2.7 and python3.8. I'd like to run only 3.8 but I tried that and learned that some software requires python 2. I had to completely reinstall my server to fix that.
So, pip runs python2.7 and pip3 runs python3.8.

I believe certbot is using pip which runs python2.7 and it fails.
I tried to learn how to force it to use pip3 but learned that it can't be done.

Now my sites are down and I can't get them working.
How can I get certbot to successfully renew my certificates?

Comment: What, exactly, did you do to the python installation on your server?

Comment: I uninstalled python 2 and the server failed to work after that.

Comment: Now both python2.7 and python3.8 are on the server. I need 3.8 for my python apps to work.

Comment: Does `lsb_release -a` error or work for you when directly run?  How did you install Certbot?  Certbot is snapped now and the default mechanism for Certbot is to install via the snap, not via pip/python directly.

Comment: Thanks for responding Thomas.  
When I run: lsb_release -a  
I get:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'

I'll try installing snap.

Comment: I intstalled snapd and got this error. After installation I uninstalled certbot and tried to reinstall it per certbot docs. I got the error again:  
 system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-951399464: mount failed: Operation not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

try setting it using update-alternatives :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 10
```

you can then swtich using this

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and select python3.8 before running certbot

Comment: I did this but I have already uninstalled certbot. Now I can't install certbot because I have to use snapd and snapd does not work.

Comment: is this not working     ` sudo apt update ;  
sudo apt install snapd ; 
sudo snap install certbot --classic ` ;

Comment: You can also try  :  [link ] (https://ixnfo.com/en/installing-certbot-in-ubuntu.html )

Comment: Before I tried this I ran: sudo certbot --version and it returned: certbot 0.40.0  
I ran: sudo apt install python3-certbot-apache  
Then ran sudo certbot --version again. This time  it returned the same error again.
So, it appears that the python3-certbot-apache plugin is causing the problem. I still can't get my sites to run.

Comment: Are you running sudo apt install python3-certbot-apache  this after setting python version to 3.8 using sudo update-alternatives --config python ?

Comment: Yes. I ran update-alternatives as you suggested and entered 2 which was the selection for python3.8. After I reinstalled certbot I ran: sudo certbot --version and it worked. From there I installed python3-certbot-apache and it stopped working. 
I reran the update-alternatives and reselected python3.8  but it did not help.